# How do I get the text of a capybara element including leading whitespace.

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, capybara

I am trying to write an rspec/capybara/selenium spec that deals with verifying of whitespace. Basically I have a form that can be filled out and once it is saved, the information renders as a row in a table. The issue that I am having is that once I get to a certain td or span and I call `.text` on it, what is being returned is stripped of the leading and trailing white space. So if you look at the sample below, if I call `find('#one').text` what is returned is `'FOOO'`. What I want to be returned is `'   FOOO   '` (I.E. including the leading and trailing whitespace).

```
<tr id="myRow">
    <td id="one">
        <span>  FOOO   </span>
    </td>
    <td id="two">
        <span>  BAR      </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Try this xpath `//td[@id='one']/span`

Comment: @Rajagopalan What difference do you think changing to XPath would make here when the question is about the text content not finding the element?

Comment: He is not pointing to the exact node from which he wants to extract the text.

Comment: @Rajagopalan That's not really relevant here, since if that made a difference then you'd just expect the return to have even more whitespace (the whitespace inside the td).  The issue is, as mentioned in my answer, that browsers ignore/collapse most normal whitespace in HTML documents when displaying the document.  Also if selecting the exact element was going to make a difference the OP would be better just sticking with CSS `#one span` than swapping to XPath.

Answer (score 0):

The leading and trailing whitespace would be collapsed/ignored by your browser so Capybara does the same. If you want that whitespace to actually be visible in the browser you need to replace the spaces with non-breaking spaces (&nbsp;) in your HTML and then Capybara will return them as well.

Comment: Is it? Can you locate one of the above text node by writing `//span[text()='FOOO']` ?

Comment: @Rajagopalan No you can't because XPath is applied to the literal document.  However a browser processes that document and applies the HTML rules for ignoring/collapsing a lot of the whitespace in the document (load the OPs HTML in a browser and see if the leading and trailing whitespace shows - hint: it doesn't)

Comment: If I load in the recent version of firefox, it collapses the spaces but If I load in in Firefox ESR last version, it doesn't collapses the spaces.

Comment: @Rajagopalan no clue what you've done to your FF 52.8.1 ESR  then, because it behaves just like the current release on mine (with regards to whitespace collapsing during display).  Collapsing of whitespace has been part of the HTML spec for a very long time, and if it wasn't done correctly in FF52 it would have broken pretty much every website out there.

Comment: I don't know that's the way it's appear to me. Its firefox 52.7